# what is the value of an array element if I don't assign it myself

Tags: c++, arrays

what would be the result if I wrote this

```
int array1[2];
cout << array1[0] ;
```

and how can I do this pseudocode :

```
if array1[0] doesn't have a value then assign its value to 1
```

I'm using C++ on DevCPP

Comment: Without a magic null value, your second point is really only possible with pointers or something like Boost's Optional.

Answer (score 8):

The elements of `array` are *uninitialized*, and it is *undefined behaviour* to read them before writing to them. Your program is ill-formed. There is no way to "check" for this; it is *your* responsibility to write a correct program.

Comment: Being asked a simple question "Mom gives you 3 apples and dad gives 4 apples, how many apples do you have now?" C++ programmer will always answer "Undefined, I don't know how many apples I had before"

Comment: @Tejs: Well, yes: C++ doesn't spend extra energy on putting your code in a sandbox and hold your hand, because it trusts you to know what you're doing. Since the code is written at writing time, there's generally no need for a dynamic check whether something has been initialized, and hence you don't have to pay for such a check.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, but since working with C++, even in C# land I keep initializing all my variables, even when I don't need to =D

Comment: @Tejs: I'd say "initialize if and when you need to". If you're setting up a large buffer to read from a file, you may *not* wish to spend the time zeroing it out, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

The initial value of unassigned array values is undefined (unless the array element type is a class/struct, in which case the default constructor will be called for each array element).  In your first example, the behavior is undefined since you have not initialized the array element before using it.

If you want to retain an "unassigned" status then you need to use a class that encapsulates this, for example using the nullable pattern for value types.

Consider using [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html): you'd declare the array as `boost::optional<int> array1[2];` and then you can test `if (array1[0])` to see if that particular element has a value.

Answer (score 3):

There is one point that the answers I'm seeing thus far seem to have missed. It depends on where your array is defined.

If the array is local to a function, like:

```
int f() { 
    int array1[2];
    cout << array1[0] ;
}
```

...then the other answers are correct: the content of `array1` contains unspecified values, and your attempt to read the value and send it to `cout` gives undefined behavior.

On the other hand, you may have defined `array1` as a global variable:

```
int array1[2];

int f() { 
    cout << array1[0];
}
```

In this case, the content of `array1` is required to be initialized to 0 for any arithmetic type (or NULL for an array of pointers). In a case like this, writing out the value in `array1[0]` is perfectly fine and gives defined results -- it must be 0. In this case, there is no any way to tell whether an element of an array containing the value `0` has that value because it was automatically initialized to 0, or was assigned that value later.

If you really need to know whether a value has been written to a variable, it's possible to write a class that will do that:

```
template <class T>
class value { 
     T val;
     bool assigned;
public:
     value(T const init=T()) : assigned(false), val(init) {}

     value &operator=(T const &t) { 
         assigned = true;
         val = t;
     }
     operator T() { return val; }

     bool was_assigned() { return assigned; }
};

// ...

value<int> array2[2];

if (!array2[0].was_assigned())
    array2[0] = 1;
```

It's *usually* easier and more efficient to just define the type to always start out initialized to a known value, so you never really care about whether it's been assigned to or not though. In short, although this supports what you've asked for, my immediate reaction is that there's probably a better/cleaner way to accomplish your ultimate goal. Before you even consider using something like this, I'd *strongly* recommend stepping back from what you're doing, and trying to figure out if there's a better way to do it. My guess is that there is/will be (and if you can't find it, you might want to ask another question, telling us about why you're trying to do this, to see if somebody can see a more direct way to accomplish your goal).

Comment: For your consideration: More constructors for your value class.  A default, which sets assigned to false.  A seperate one that takes T, and sets assigned to true.  And a user defined copy constructor which sets assigned to true.  That way, the value is considered assigned to if it was initialized from another value, or from a T. **Edit:** actually, strike the user defined copy constructor.  That way if you initialize from an uninitialized value, it keeps the unassigned property.

Answer (score 1):

As far I remember that depend on the OS

Comment: It depends upon the compiler, though the compiler may delegate to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

As other users said, you need to initialize `a` then use a for loop to test each value one by one and modify them, if they fulfill a condition, I leave you a C snippet:

```
/* Variable declaration and initialization to 0s (You can use another value as default )*/
int a[ 5 ] = { 0 };

/* If the array[ i ] has 0 as value */
for( i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   if ( a[ i ] == 0  ){ 
      a[ i ] = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: *"You can use another value as default"* -- No you can't.  Not unless you explicitly specify every element.  If you provide an initializer list to an array, even if you don't actually specify any elements, all unspecified elements will be value initialized.  Value initialization for ints means initialization to zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialise the element yourself, the element will obtain the value from the memory location it is stored on now (and will most probably convert it to its data type). Consider this program :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int foo(int A[])
{
    cout << A[0] << A[1];
}

int main()
{
    int array[2];
    foo(array);
}
```

This will give the output 00.

But now consider this code :

```
int main()
{
    int array[2];
    cout << array[0] << array[1];
}
```

It will give some random integer output. This is so because the uninitialised array picks up the value stored on the memory location it now occupies. You can check its memory adress by `&array[0]` and print it in different data types for some thought provoking questions.

eg: `cout << &array[0] << char(array[0]) << bool(array[0])` etc.